# I pass right through you

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I pass right through you,
Make no mistake.
My identity, do
These questions make:

Perfect? You just hurt my head
Discomfited? I made the bed
Wanted? Little trouble overflows
Buried? Deliver the final blows

Who am I?

Comment: I like this riddle's style, but it's to difficult for me XD. A desrved upvote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are

> A nail. It passes right through whatever it is hammered into.

Perfect?

> Hit the nail on the head

Discomfited?

> A bed of nails is less than ideal

Wanted?

> This is the "For want of a nail" proverb about problems escalating - neat clue, answer courtesy of Stiv

Buried?

> The final nail in the coffin

Comment: Looks good to me :) I think your missing one is the phrase about: rot13(Sbe jnag bs n anvy gur fubr jnf ybfg; sbe jnag bs n fubr gur ubefr jnf ybfg; naq sbe jnag bs n ubefr gur zna jnf ybfg) +1

Comment: @Stiv Correct; they're all rot13(vqvbzf). The answer needs a bit of improvement for 3/4 but otherwise it's totally correct.